POST http://localhost:5000/api/scan/start 400 (Bad Request)
Hi guys I am trying to make an audit web page and I want to test a scan using Openvas which I have hosted in a docker container, when I start the scan I get error Dashboard.js:13
**POST http://localhost:5000/api/scan/start 400 (Bad Request)   My native language is Spanish, I apologize if there is a discrepancy in the translation.
**
in the frontend where I request scanning is Dashboard.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Dashboard.css';

function Dashboard() {
    const [target, setTarget] = useState('');
    const [configId, setConfigId] = useState('');
    const [scanId, setScanId] = useState('');
    const [status, setStatus] = useState('');
    const [report, setReport] = useState('');

    const startScan = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/scan/start', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ target, configId }),
            });
            const data = await response.json();
            if (data.success) {
                setScanId(data.scanId);
            } else {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };

    const checkStatus = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/scan/status/${scanId}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            setStatus(data.status);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };

    const getReport = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/scan/report/${scanId}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            setReport(data.report);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="dashboard-container">
            <h2>Dashboard</h2>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Target</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={target}
                    onChange={(e) => setTarget(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Config ID</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={configId}
                    onChange={(e) => setConfigId(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <button onClick={startScan}>Start Scan</button>
            <div>
                <button onClick={checkStatus}>Check Status</button>
                <p>Status: <strong>{status}</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={getReport}>Get Report</button>
                <p>Report: <strong>{report}</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;

Backend
This is the docker-compose.yml file
version: '3'

services:
  openvas:
    image: mikesplain/openvas
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "9390:9390"
      - "9391:9391"
    environment:
      - PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - openvas_data:/var/lib/openvas
      - openvas_logs:/var/log/openvas
      - openvas_etc:/etc/openvas

volumes:
  openvas_data:
  openvas_logs:
  openvas_etc:

The index.js is configured as follows:
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const scanRoutes = require('./routes/scanRoutes');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI).then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB connected');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error);
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/scan', scanRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

I have this scanRoutes.js file
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { startScan, getScanStatus, getScanReport } = require('../controllers/scanController');

router.post('/start', startScan);
router.get('/status/:scanId', getScanStatus);
router.get('/report/:scanId', getScanReport);

module.exports = router;

I have this scanController.js file
const axios = require('axios');

// Configuración de Axios para OpenVAS
const openvasInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:9390',
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
});

exports.startScan = async (req, res) => {
    const { target } = req.body;
    if (!target) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Target is required' });
    }

    try {
        const response = await openvasInstance.post('/scan/start', { target });
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, scanId: response.data.scanId });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al iniciar escaneo:', error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to start scan' });
    }
};

exports.getScanStatus = async (req, res) => {
    const { scanId } = req.params;
    try {
        const response = await openvasInstance.get(`/scan/status/${scanId}`);
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, status: response.data.status });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al obtener estado del escaneo:', error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to get scan status' });
    }
};

exports.getScanReport = async (req, res) => {
    const { scanId } = req.params;
    try {
        const response = await openvasInstance.get(`/scan/report/${scanId}`);
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, report: response.data.report });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al obtener reporte del escaneo:', error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to get scan report' });
    }
};


I tried to try with another Openvas image but it didn't work, I really can't find logical errors in the code, that's why I come here since I'm new to using web languages. I thank you in advance if you can tell me why it does not scan.
Note: My native language is Spanish, I apologize if there is a discrepancy in the translation.

The 400 Bad Request is a generic error that the payload being sent is not correct and it's a client issue. By looking at your code, it's probably being raised by your startScan function, which means, the req.body (target) is not present

You are currently trying to use a 5 year old and deprecated 3rdparty docker image together with a only few months old OpenAPI based API of the openvas-scanner which is still under heavy development. Better try to base your work on the official community containers and the GMP API, various info should be available from Greenbone.
